# Retired soldier saves female alien from aircraft crash

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been trying to find a book I read a few years ago (5+). The plot involve a retired military person ( maybe a general ) solo sailing across the ocean when an aircraft crashes nearby and he saves the female alien pilot. I read the book in paperback so don't know if it was ever hard cover.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds to me like [David Weber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Weber)'s [The Apocalypse Troll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Apocalypse_Troll).

> The badly injured human pilot survives her crash landing and is rescued by a passing yacht. The yacht is crewed singlehanded by a US Navy SEAL on his retirement cruise (Captain Dick Aston). The very young looking pilot is in a coma and has a hole right through her. The wound starts to heal before Dick’s eyes and he spends the next 4 days feeding her while she remains in a healing trance. When she wakes she informs Dick she is Colonel Ludmilla Leonovna of the Terran Marines and no she isn't a Russian.

Comment: Darn, it was my thought as well.  Include some points on why this story matches the question though.

Comment: @Jim2B I was partway through writing some and suddenly Sean has put some more details in for me!

Comment: Yeah, some of those guys are awfully fast!  I wish I could type that fast!

Comment: @Jim2b It's copied from the Wikipedia page...

Comment: It was a quite enjoyable read too.  Nothing too deep or meaningful but fun.